# why is probability generating function $G_x (0) = p_0$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

By definition, 
$$\sum_x s^x  p_x$$
since $s$ is $0$, the whole thing equals $0$.
So shouldnt it equal 0? 
Or is $p_0$ also $0$?

Answer (score 2):

In a polynomial $P(s) = \sum_{j=0}^n c_j s^j$ or power series $G(s) = \sum_{j=0}^\infty c_j s^j$, the $j=0$ term is
$c_0 s^0 = c_0$.  Then substituting $s=0$, all the terms are $0$ **except** for
the $j=0$ term, which remains $c_0$.  In effect, power series and polynomials use the convention $0^0 = 1$.

Comment: Cheers. Is $0^0 =1$ ?

Comment: $0^0$ is an indeterminate form.  I am not saying it **is** $1$, I am saying the conventional notation of polynomials and power series treats it as $1$.